# Setting "outside" bottom edge for MaterialCardView doesn't work as expected

Tags: android, tooltip, material-components-android, materialcardview

I'm trying to build a `tooltip` with shadow like the following image:

[image]

I was able to do so by using an Image as `background`. But I couldn't apply shadows to it. So, after searching I found [this article](https://blog.octo.com/en/android-materialshapedrawable/), it uses `MaterialCardView` and applying `MaterialShapeDrawable` to it as a `background`.

I have tried the following code:

```
    val shapeDrawable = MaterialShapeDrawable()
    val shapeAppearanceModel =
        ShapeAppearanceModel.builder().setBottomEdge(TriangleEdgeTreatment(20f, false)).build()
    shapeDrawable.shapeAppearanceModel = shapeAppearanceModel
    materialDialog.background = shapeDrawable
```

XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/width_custom_marker"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:ignore="Overdraw">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/materialCard"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/width_custom_marker"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**My issue** is that while setting the `inside` flag with `false` for this object `TriangleEdgeTreatment(30f, true)` it doesn't work as expected. However, setting the flag with `true` works properly.

TriangleEdgeTreatment(30f, false)

[image]

TriangleEdgeTreatment(30f, true)

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to add android:clipToPadding="false" and android:clipToPadding="false" to the parent view

Comment: I tried it before. It doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can achieve it using:

```
  <LinearLayout
      android:clipChildren="false"
      android:clipToPadding="false"
      android:padding="16dp"
      ..>

        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
         ../>
```

and applying the `TriangleEdgeTreatment`:

```
float size = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.triangle_size); //16dp
TriangleEdgeTreatment triangleEdgeTreatment = new TriangleEdgeTreatment(size,false);

MaterialCardView cardView = findViewById(R.id.card);
cardView.setShapeAppearanceModel(cardView.getShapeAppearanceModel()
    .toBuilder()
    .setBottomEdge(triangleEdgeTreatment)
    .build());
```

[image]